# How to calculate billing characters of Vertex AI in offline mode, without using the FREE Post API?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, offline-mode

I am trying to calculate the number (and if possible the exact list) of billable Vertex AI characters of a text.

Apart from the FREE API [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/get-token-count#gemini-get-token-count-samples-python_vertex_ai_sdk), is there a way to implement locally the method to calculate those billing characters ?

For instance with chatGPT and tiktoken [here](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken), you can do it offline.

The advantages is that I would have :

- no need internet connection
- no limitation of parallel calls
- exact list of billable characters

Thank you in advance !

Cheers,